# Stop/Start SVG-Rotation via Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, svg, rotation

I need a little bit of help. 
In the following code, I want to control the rotation of the star via onmouse-event.

If you move the mouse over the star, it is supposed to rotate.

I thought about changing the `transform` in `attributeName` to something different when the mouse is not over the star via `roationon()/off()` functions so that the rotation doesn't work but I have no idea how to do that.

I appreciate every help I can get.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<html>

<body>

<script>
function rotationon() {}
function rotationoff() {}
</script>

<svg height="2000" width="2000">
<polygon id="stern1" points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180" fill="yellow" transform="translate(100, 100)" onmouseover="rotationon()" onmouseout="rotationoff()" >
<animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        begin="0s"
        dur="5s"
        type="rotate"
        from="0 100 100"
        to="360 100 100"
        repeatCount="indefinite" 
    />
    </polygon>
</svg>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just out of interest, if thats 'all' you want to do, you can actually do it without javascript at all, like http://jsfiddle.net/xaM6q/ but I suspect you want a better solution to tailor for other bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few different ways to approach this, depending on what its going to integrate with, and how well it will play with other browsers.

My gut instinct would be to say ultimately, its worth using one of the SVG libs out there, like Raphael, snap.svg, Pablo.js etc. They will help with some of the issues likely to be faced.

You can also just use pure SVG like I mentioned http://jsfiddle.net/xaM6q/

However, to use the method you are trying, you may want to use something like beginElement() and endElement, so the code could look something like the following...fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/xaM6q/2/

```
<script>
   function rotationon(evt){
        document.getElementById('myanim').beginElement();    
   }
   function rotationoff(){
        document.getElementById('myanim').endElement();
   }
 </script>

<svg height="2000" width="2000">
   <g transform="translate(100,100)">
     <polygon id="stern1" points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180" fill="yellow"  onmouseover="rotationon()" onmouseout="rotationoff()" >
       <animateTransform
         id="myanim"
         attributeName="transform"
         begin="indefinite"
         dur="5s"
         type="rotate"
         from="0 100 100"
         to="360 100 100"
         fill="freeze"
         repeatCount="indefinite" 
    />
   </polygon>
  </g>
```

Couple of things worth noting. I've added a g element to help keep the transformation in place, as you probably want that (without it, you may find it moves away). Also the animation may be a bit erratic depending how you want it to stop (I've added 'fill=freeze'), and what happens with events mid animation.

Its worth knowing all of this to get to know SVG animations, but as mentioned, I would probably still look at using a 3rd party lib and control the rotation manually, rather than using the animate tag, so you can halt/restart a rotation at any angle easily.